# ActiveMQ Consumers are not listening after some time

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

Currently I have setup ActiveMq and Python Stomp Listener in two servers.

But after sometime, Python consumer is not fetching pending messages in the queue. But ActiveMq console is showing that the consumer is still Active.

Here is a screenshot

[image: consumer active]

1. When i restarted the Python Listener, it started fetching messages.
2. When i added heartbeat from Python Listener, it fetched message and while processioning the message, the connection disconnected and it tried to reconnect. But it gives an error **can't start new thread**

```html
def listen():
    try:
        conn.set_listener('RPAListener', RPAListener())
        conn.connect(wait=True)
        connect_id = random.randint(1, 20)
        conn.subscribe(CONFIG.get('ActiveMQ', 'process_queue'), id=connect_id, ack='client', headers={
            'consumer.prefetchSize': 1,
            'activemq.prefetchSize': 1,
        })
        logger.info(
            "ACTIVE_MQ_LISTENER | LISTEN_STARTED (HOST:{}, PORT:{}, ) | LISTENING_TO : {}, connect_id : {}".format(
                CONFIG.get('ActiveMQ', 'host'), CONFIG.get('ActiveMQ', 'port'), CONFIG.get('ActiveMQ', 'process_queue'),
                connect_id))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.info("STARED INITIATION PROCESS")
    listen()
    while True:
        time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Without code sample it will be hard to help you

Comment: i added the listener code